# Pay pall Developer Mode Integartion

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I searched lot but unable to resolved pay pal issue. "
PayPal cannot process this transaction because of a problem with the seller's website. Please contact the seller directly to resolve this problem." 
here is simple code .

#### product kit 
 $250

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="paypal">
<input type='hidden' name='business' value='syhunk835@gmail.com'>
<input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='Camera'>
<input type='hidden' name='item_number' value='1'>
<input type='hidden' name='amount' value='0.01'>
<input type='hidden' name='no_shipping' value='1'>
<input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='USD'>
<input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='http://SITE NAME/payment.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://SITE NAME/cancel.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://SITE NAME/success.php'>
<!-- COPY and PASTE Your Button Code -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="### COPY FROM BUTTON CODE ###"><input type="image"src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
</form>
```

I tried with chf-8 but still same issue. I do not know where is I am wrong.